# What does this awk script do?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a script that I need to reverse engineer, but the script appears to be broken. Below is a segment of the script around where it breaks.

```
awk 'BEGIN{while ((getline line < "file1") > 0){F=../file2
```

With similar statements repeated one after the other. The obvious problem is that there's an opening `'` and `{`, but no closing ones. I could try to fix this, but I don't really know what this is even trying to do. I have some experience with linux commands but not a whole lot.

1. I understand that `file2` is a file location, but what is `F=`?
2. There's the beginning `'`, but why? Should there be a closing one somewhere, or should that not even be there in the first place?

Anyone know, or have any ideas, as to what this is supposed to be?

Comment: Are you sure there is no closing quote?  Single quoted strings can be multiline, and it is common to have the close quote (and '}') on another line.

Comment: Yes, there is more stuff on other lines, but the opening and closing brackets or quotes still don't add up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this awk line is broken in several ways.

1. It should have a terminating `'`, the `'`'s wrap the command/script you pass to the awk command to run.
2. `F=../file1` looks like variable assignment, but it's unquoted so awk thinks you're attempting to write a regular expression, which is unterminated by a second `/`.
3. There is no terminating `}`.

The script looks incomplete since it should break down to this:

```
# read from file1 until EOF
while ((getline line < "file1") > 0) {
    F="../file2"
    # what now?
}
```